# Как отсортировать многомерный массив?

Tags: php

Есть массив примерно такого вида:

```
 $arr = array("string1" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "6"), 
                        1 => array("text", "text2", "5"),
                        2 => array("text", "text2", "4")),
     "string2" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "7"), 
                        1 => array("text", "text2", "1"),
                        2 => array("text", "text2", "8")),
     "string3" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "2"), 
                        1 => array("text", "text2", "3"),
                        2 => array("text", "text2", "9")),
 );
```

Нужно отсортировать массив по последнему значению, от большего числа к меньшему (то есть 9,8,7,6,5,4...) и вывести. Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Comment: а по скольку будут потом подмассивы?

Comment: подмассивов будет очень много

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сформировать общий массив указанных данных с числовым ключом и отсортировать по ключу, потом отсортировать исходный массив по убыванию и, наконец, в обратном порядке вернуть данные:

```
$arr = array("string1" => array(0 => array("text", "text6", "6"), 
                            1 => array("text", "text5", "5"),
                            2 => array("text", "text4", "4")),
         "string2" => array(0 => array("text", "text7", "7"), 
                            1 => array("text", "text1", "1"),
                            2 => array("text", "text8", "8")),
         "string3" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "2"), 
                            1 => array("text", "text3", "3"),
                            2 => array("text", "text9", "9")),
         );

function merge_all($item, $key){
    array_walk($item, 'merge_string');
}

function merge_string($item, $key){
    global $common;
    $common[end($item)] = $item; 
}

function return_all(&$item, $key){
    array_walk($item, 'return_string');
}

function return_string(&$item, $key){
    global $common;
    $item = array_pop($common);
}

$common = array();
array_walk($arr, 'merge_all');
ksort($common);
krsort($arr);
array_walk($arr, 'return_all');
var_dump($arr);
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=3)
  'string3' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text9' (length=5)
          2 => string '9' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text8' (length=5)
          2 => string '8' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text7' (length=5)
          2 => string '7' (length=1)
  'string2' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text6' (length=5)
          2 => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text5' (length=5)
          2 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text4' (length=5)
          2 => string '4' (length=1)
  'string1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text3' (length=5)
          2 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text2' (length=5)
          2 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text1' (length=5)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
```

P.S. Если надо отсортировать по убыванию string1, string2, string3 и в каждом из них провести сортировку по убыванию числовых данных - это другая, более простая задача:

```
$arr = array("string1" => array(0 => array("text", "text6", "6"), 
                                1 => array("text", "text05", "5"),
                                2 => array("text", "text4", "4")),
             "string2" => array(0 => array("text", "text7", "7"), 
                                1 => array("text", "text1", "1"),
                                2 => array("text", "text8", "8")),
             "string3" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "2"), 
                                1 => array("text", "text3", "3"),
                                2 => array("text", "text9", "9")),
             );


function sort_all(&$item, $key){
    global $common;
    $common = array();
    array_walk($item, 'prepare_text');
    krsort($common);
    $item = array_values($common);
}

function prepare_text(&$item, $key){
    global $common;
    $common[end($item)] = $item;
}

krsort($arr);
array_walk($arr, 'sort_all');
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Единственное, нужно что бы еще подмассивы соответствовали string1, string2, string3. Извиняюсь, может неправильно выразился.

    "string3" => array(2 => array("text", "text2", "9")
    "string2" => array(2 => array("text", "text7", "8")
    "string2" => array(0 => array("text", "text7", "7")
    "string1" => array(0 => array("text", "text6", "6")

......

Comment: тогда уточните: это принудительный обратный порядок индексов или сортировка по убыванию? В принципе, пока данные лежат во внешнем массиве, с исходным можно делать что угодно.

Comment: обычный массив, стандартный вопрос. Сортировка по ключу  с убыванием - это krsort(arr).

Comment: Это сортировка по убыванию, то есть должно получиться что то вроде:

"string3" => array(2 => array("text", "text2", "9") 
"string2" => array(2 => array("text", "text7", "8") 
"string2" => array(0 => array("text", "text7", "7") 
"string1" => array(0 => array("text", "text6", "6")

Comment: работает........

Comment: и не забудьте галочку поставить :)

Comment: Я имел ввиду что на выходе каждый подмассив должен соответствовать string1, string2 и тд.

Comment: Должно получиться вот так:
$arr["string3"] => array(2 => array("text", "text2", "9");
$arr["string2"] => array(2 => array("text", "text7", "8");
$arr["string2"] => array(0 => array("text", "text7", "7")

Я конечно дуб в этом, не знаю как по другому объяснить,

Comment: Готово, соответствует. Но это совсем просто...

Comment: Смотрите, я вывожу массив так: 
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) foreach ($v as $key => $val) echo "$k => $key => $val[0] = $val[1] = $val[2]<br>";

Мне нужно что бы вывод отсортировался по $val[2], но при этом $k и $key должны соответствовать $val[0], $val[1], $val[2]

Comment: Выводить проще через var_dump. И протестируйте ещё раз, я внёс правки.

Comment: Первые 3 строчки которые выводит ваш код:

string3 => 9 => text = text9 = 9; 
string3 => 3 => text = text3 = 3; 
string3 => 2 => text = text2 = 2; 

А должен:
string2 => 1 => text = text1 = 1;
string3 => 0 => text = text2 = 2;
string3 => 1 => text = text3 = 3;


То есть должен сортироваться по последнему эллементу, при этом stringX => key должны соответствовыть подмассивам и key не должен меняться.  Я по вашему совету все таки создал новый вопрос и там мне ответили, посмотрите если не трудно, насколько ли хорошее то решение?

Comment: Код обновлён. Смотрю

Comment: Плюс кода - что uasort стандартный (скопирован из доки). Нехороший минус, что array_push загоняет в массив  три элемента (а если их не три?). И программеры недолюбливают foreach, потому что он долгий.

Comment: В моей программе явный выигрыш по универсальности, квадратным скобкам (индексы требуют постоянного внимания), и сортируемый массив одномерный, но применена слишком красивая процедура array_walk. Вывод: если задание учебное, возьмите у конкурента.

Comment: Последний раз код обновлен 2 часа назад. Различий в работе не заметил.

Comment: код сортирует строки по убыванию и массивы по каждой строке по убыванию числа. Я про код в постскриптуме

Comment: так Вас индексы не устраивали! :) ну и проблемка получилась... готово

Comment: Спасибо конечно за потраченное время и терпение, но к сожалению ваш код поставленной задачи не выполняет. Сравните работу своего кода и того что в другой ветке и сразу все поймете.

Comment: я ответил в ту ветку :)

Comment: Попробую как нибудь по четче сформулировать задачу. Нужно что бы сортировалось не внутри stringX, а полностью весь вывод по последнему элементу. При этом подмассивы должны соответствовать ключам.

Comment: если мои результаты соответствуют, то особо нет смысла. Но постановка задачи не должна вызывать коллизий.

Comment: Попробуйте сравнить свое решение с решением в той ветке. Сравните вывод.

Comment: в той ветке другое моё решение с результатами.

Comment: По-моему, Вы меня слегка запутали. Если порядок string1, string2, string3 Вас устраивает, закомментируйте в том решении третью строчку снизу.,

Comment: Получил результаты по чужому решению.. В первый раз вижу, что массивы надо слить в один

Comment: В том то и дело что порядок не устраивает. Не должны string1, string2, string3 идти по порядку, ведь нужно сортировать по последнему элементу, а у вас сортируется только внутри stringX. Цифра "9" соответствует $arr[string3][2], цифра "8" $arr[string2][2], цифра "7" $arr[string2][0], цифра "6" $arr[string1][0] и тд. В таком порядке должен быть вывод.

Comment: Лучший способ  - показать требуемый результат. Если многомерный массив не нужен - значит, всё нормально. А если Вас устраивает и фиксированная размерность string1, string2 и string3 в условии - то и подавно.

Comment: По-моему, лучшее решение  - чтобы Вы взяли за основу результаты устраивающей Вас программы и отредактировали вопрос. Разумеется, речь о той ветке.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32033/discussion-on-answer-by-yuri-negometyanov----).