# сортировка многомерного массива php

Tags: php

Есть массив примерно такого вида:

```
$arr = array("string1" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "6"), 
                                1 => array("text", "text2", "5"),
                                2 => array("text", "text2", "4")),
             "string2" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "7"), 
                                1 => array("text", "text2", "1"),
                                2 => array("text", "text2", "8")),
             "string3" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "2"), 
                                1 => array("text", "text2", "3"),
                                2 => array("text", "text2", "9")),
       );
```

Нужно отсортировать массив по последнему значению, от большего числа к меньшему (то есть 9,8,7,6,5,4...) и вывести. 
Например я вывожу информацию из массива так:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
foreach ($value as $k => $v)
echo "$key => $k => $v[0] = $v[1] = $v[2]<br>";
```

Мне нужно что бы вывод отсортировался по `$v[2]`, но при этом `$key` и `$k` должны соответствовать `$v[0]`, `$v[1]`, `$v[2]`. Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468692/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-php

Comment: Попросили создать новый вопрос, так как в комментариях плохо видно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю преобразовать двумерный массив в одномерный:

```
$arr = array(
    "string1" => array(
        0 => array("text", "text2", "6"), 
        1 => array("text", "text2", "5"),
        2 => array("text", "text2", "4")
    ), "string2" => array(
        0 => array("text", "text2", "7"), 
        1 => array("text", "text2", "1"),
        2 => array("text", "text2", "8")
    ), "string3" => array(
        0 => array("text", "text2", "2"), 
        1 => array("text", "text2", "3"),
        2 => array("text", "text2", "9")
    )
);

$newArr = array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) 
        array_push($newArr, array($key, $v[0], $v[1], $v[2]));
```

А потом использовать [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) для сортировки массива по полю:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[3] == $b[3]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[3] < $b[3]) ? -1 : 1;
}       
usort($newArr, "cmp");
var_dump($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Идея с использованием usort неплоха, но преобразовывать ничего не надо:

```
$arr = array("string1" => array(0 => array("text", "text6", "6"), 
                            1 => array("text", "text05", "5"),
                            2 => array("text", "text4", "4")),
         "string2" => array(0 => array("text", "text7", "7"), 
                            1 => array("text", "text1", "1"),
                            2 => array("text", "text8", "8")),
         "string3" => array(0 => array("text", "text2", "2"), 
                            1 => array("text", "text3", "3"),
                            2 => array("text", "text9", "9")),
         );

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if (end($a) == end($b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (end($a) > end($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

function sort_all(&$item, $key){
    usort($item, 'cmp');
    $item = array_values($item);
}

krsort($arr);
array_walk($arr, 'sort_all');
var_dump($arr);
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=3)
  'string3' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text9' (length=5)
          2 => string '9' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text3' (length=5)
          2 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text2' (length=5)
          2 => string '2' (length=1)
  'string2' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text8' (length=5)
          2 => string '8' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text7' (length=5)
          2 => string '7' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text1' (length=5)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
  'string1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text6' (length=5)
          2 => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text05' (length=6)
          2 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'text' (length=4)
          1 => string 'text4' (length=5)
          2 => string '4' (length=1)
```